# Set table vs Map table

Tags: database, oracle, database-design

I have a table:

employee

```
id  name salary
1   A    100
2   B    200
3   C    300
4   D    400
```

I want to add another table describing employee_responsibilities. I have 2 approaches:

Approach 1:

employee table remains same and employee_responsibility table:

```
id employee_id responsibility
1  1           X
2  1           Y
3  1           YY
4  1           ZZ
5  2           QQ
6  2           WW
```

Approach 2:

employee table:

employee

```
id  name salary set_id
1   A    100    1
2   B    200    2
3   C    300    3
4   D    400    4
```

employee_responsibility table:

```
id responsibility
1  X
1  Y
1  YY
1  ZZ
2  QQ
2  WW
```

Which approach is better? What are the pros and cons of each approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This completely depends on how you are using this data.  For a typical OLTP environment, you would probably want something like:

employee

```
id  name salary
1   A    100
2   B    200
3   C    300
4   D    400
```

responsibility

```
id responsibility
1  X
2  Y
3  YY
4  ZZ
5  QQ
6  WW
```

employee_responsibility

```
employee_id    responsibility_id
1              1
1              2
1              3
1              4
2              5
2              6
```

If this were a data warehouse or something else that read performance is more important than flexibility, then a less normalized design would be more appropriate.

Comment: wouldn't employee_responsibility table need its own primary key?

Comment: @dang: Assuming that each employee can only be assigned each responsibility once, then making `(employee_id, responsibility_id)` the primary key is reasonable.